# Why I can send packets through `eth0` but not `eth1` in Docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, scapy

I created a docker container and connected it to two bridge networks as:

```
# network 1
docker network create --driver=bridge network1 --subnet=172.56.0.0/24

#network 2
docker network create --driver=bridge network2 --subnet=172.56.1.0/24

docker run \
    --name container \
    --privileged \
    --cap-add=ALL -d \
    -v /dev:/dev \
    --network network1 \
    -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
    container-image tail -f /dev/null

docker network connect network2 container
```

Now, if I run `ip addr` inside container, I have two ethernet network interfaces:

```
6551: eth0@if6552: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:38:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.56.0.2/24 brd 172.56.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6553: eth1@if6554: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:38:01:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.56.1.2/24 brd 172.56.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm using scapy to send/receive through IP and ICMP protocol, with something like this:

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys

src = sys.argv[1]
dst = sys.argv[2]

msg = "Hello World!"

packet = IP(src = src, dst = dst)/ICMP()/msg

data = sr1(packet).load.decode('utf-8')
print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

I'm able to run it when `src = 172.56.0.2` and `dst = www.google.com` or when I'm using `eth0` as a source, but if I change it to `src = 172.56.1.2`, it won't work at all. Is there anything wrong with my `eth1` interface here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What underlying issue are you trying to solve? Why is it important what bridge is used for going out to the Internet?

Comment: @BMitch I believe `eth0` is used for connecting it Internet, cause this is the result of `ip route`: ```default via 172.56.0.1 dev eth0
172.56.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.56.0.2
172.56.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.56.1.2``` Also, I'm trying to simulate behavior of network switches by using these two *virtual network switches*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the routing table. Take a look at `conf.route`:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> conf.route
Network     Netmask        Gateway     Iface  Output IP   Metric
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0        172.56.0.1  eth0   172.56.0.2  0
127.0.0.0   255.0.0.0      0.0.0.0     lo     127.0.0.1   1
172.56.0.0  255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0     eth0   172.56.0.2  0
172.56.1.0  255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0     eth1   172.56.1.2  0
```

In the above route table, the default route is via `172.56.0.1`. Any attempt to reach an address that isn't on a directly connected network will be sent via the default gateway, which is only reachable via `eth0`. If you want your request to go out `eth1`, you need to modify your routing table. For example, we can replace the default route:

```
>>> conf.route.delt(net='0.0.0.0/0', gw='172.56.0.1', metric=0)
>>> conf.route.add(net='0.0.0.0/0', gw='172.56.1.1', metric=0)
>>> conf.route
Network     Netmask        Gateway     Iface  Output IP   Metric
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0        172.56.1.1  eth1   172.56.1.2  0
127.0.0.0   255.0.0.0      0.0.0.0     lo     127.0.0.1   1
172.56.0.0  255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0     eth0   172.56.0.2  0
172.56.1.0  255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0     eth1   172.56.1.2  0
```

With this modified routing table, our requests will be sent out `eth1`.

If we assume that the appropriate gateway will always be the `.1` address associated with the source interface, we can rewrite your code like this to automatically apply the correct route:

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys
import ipaddress

src = ipaddress.ip_interface(sys.argv[1])
dst = sys.argv[2]

gw = src.network[1]
conf.route.routes = [route for route in conf.route.routes if route[1] != 0]
conf.route.add(net='0.0.0.0/0', gw=f'{gw}', metric=0)

msg = "Hello World!"

packet = IP(src = f'{src.ip}', dst=dst)/ICMP()/msg
data = sr1(packet).load.decode('utf-8')
print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

With the modified code, the first argument (`sys.argv[1]`) needs to be an `address/mask` expression. This now works with both interface addresses:

```
root@bacb8598b801:~# python sendpacket.py 172.56.0.2/24 8.8.8.8
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.*
Received 2 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
Received 'Hello World!'
root@bacb8598b801:~# python sendpacket.py 172.56.1.2/24 8.8.8.8
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.*
Received 2 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
Received 'Hello World!'
```

Watching `tcpdump` on the two bridge interfaces, you can see that traffic is being routed via the expected interface for each source address.